# Slow behaviour of CEDET

Tags: cedet

I started using CEDET with Emacs and although it works fine sometimes it is too slow.

For example if I write `std::` and wait for suggestions then in the minibuffer says `parsing file.cpp (LL) done`
and for 1-2 seconds it freezes and I can't write. Then if I repeat it although it doesn't say anything in the minibuffer it still freezes the same. Eventually it shows the list of possible items but after that "freeze time".

Why is that happening? How can I fix it? I don't thing that this is the default behaviour as it is very annoying.

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  I.e. please `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @Stefan I would have thought that in a package so frequently used if this was a bug it would have been already fixed.

Comment: @Adam Unfortunately, it's not used as frequently, as you might think.

Comment: However, it might be simply parsing the project files (as well as system includes). So whether this is a bug on not, depends on how often it happens, and whether it re-parses files it doesn't really need to.

Comment: @Dmitry it happens every time I write `std::`.

Comment: @Adam Even if you wait a while for parsing to finish, the first time it starts? Then Stefan's suggestion might be best.

Comment: @Dmitry yes that is the issue. The parsing is finished every time.